# Find Var(Y) given Y is uniformly distributed in (X,1) and X is uniformly distributed in (0,1)

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance

I approached this problem by using the formula Var(Y) = $E(Y^2)-E(Y)^{2}$.

E(Y) = $\frac{3}{4}$

However, my difficulty was finding $E(Y^2)$. Can someone explain why this integral setup is wrong?

$E(Y^2) =  \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} y^2  dy dx $

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)?

Answer (score 4):

It should be $\int_0^1 \int_x^1 \frac{y^2}{1-x} \, dy \, dx$, since the density of $Y$ given $X=x$ is $f_{Y \mid X=x}(y) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ on $[x, 1]$.